# Property does not exist on type typeof app.module

Tags: angular, ngrx, ng-modules

```
import { StoreModule } from "@ngrx/store";
import { currentPurchase } from "../shared/index";

@NgModule({
 imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}),
        HttpModule,
        StoreModule.provideStore({currentPurchase})
    ]
..
```

I am getting `Property currentPurchase' does not exist on type typeof app.module.` The imported reducer looks like this:

```
import { ActionReducer, Action } from "@ngrx/store";
import { ActionType } from "./action-type";
import { PurchaseModel } from "../purchase/purchase.model";

export const currentPurchase: ActionReducer<PurchaseModel> = (state:PurchaseModel = new PurchaseModel(), action:Action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case ActionType.SET_PURCHASE:
            return (action.payload !== null) ? action.payload : new PurchaseModel();
        case ActionType.UPDATE_PURCHASE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload);
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Also:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the import statement towards your currentPurchase correct? This error is typically shown when imports are missing/incorrect.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that, unfortunately same error.

Answer (score 1):

For your second error, you need to install the es6-shim types as described here: 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7033#issuecomment-183249303

You can do this with types in your package json as well by:

```
npm i @types/es6-shim -S
```

Comment: I installed that, but WebStorm still shows the error (even after restart)

Comment: Was the directory added to the @types in the node_modules?https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8jwwr9o2wwbuzo/Screenshot%202016-10-10%2019.34.21.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Use an untyped `function` instead of typed `const` in the reducers, e.g. like:

**Failing with ng2-final AoT:**

```
export const settings: ActionReducer<SettingsModel> = (state:SettingsModel = new SettingsModel(), action:Action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionType.SET_SETTINGS:
            return (action.payload !== null) ? action.payload : new SettingsModel();
        case ActionType.UPDATE_SETTINGS:
            console.log(Object.assign(state, {pin: Object.assign(state.pin, action.payload.pin)}));
            return Object.assign({}, state, {pin: Object.assign(state.pin, action.payload.pin)});
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

**Working with ng2-final AoT:**

```
export function settings (state:SettingsModel = new SettingsModel(), action:Action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionType.SET_SETTINGS:
            return (action.payload !== null) ? action.payload : new SettingsModel();
        case ActionType.UPDATE_SETTINGS:
            console.log(Object.assign(state, {pin: Object.assign(state.pin, action.payload.pin)}));
            return Object.assign({}, state, {pin: Object.assign(state.pin, action.payload.pin)});
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Read more about this (it wont say why): https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/190